# Core Data and multiple to-many relationships

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the folowing Core Data model:

[image: Core Data Model]

That is, ach ItemCategory belongs to a `project` (reverse: `categories`), and can optionally belong to a parent ItemCategory (`category`, reverse `subcategories`) — please ignore the rest.

Thing is, apparently I can't set both the project and the parent category for an ItemCategory. Every time I set one relationship the other relationship is set to nil. I've tried every combination of delete rule, but nothing seems to work.

Is there a fundamental Core Data restriction I'm not aware, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple to-many relationships between two entities. The important thing is that each relationship has its own inverse. Let's say we have entity **A** and **B** and we want two to-many relationships between them. You can do that.

We'll start out with

```
A <<----->> B
```

Your **A** entity will have a relationship which we'll call **bs** with an inverse which we'll call **as**. So far everything is normal.

Nothing prevents you from adding another relationship, though:

```
  <<----->>
A           B
  <<----->>
```

For the 2nd relationship, we'll name the relationship from **A** to **B** as **otherBs** and its inverse for **otherAs**.

Now **A** has two relationships to **B**, namely **bs** and **otherBs**. And the same goes for the relationships the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll vote for "doing something wrong".  :)  I just tried the simplest form of this with a Project, an ItemCategory, no attributes, no other entities, their own relationships...and it doesn't show that symptom.  This...

```
   Project *p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   ItemCategory *c1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemCategory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   ItemCategory *c2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemCategory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   c1.category = c2;
   c1.project = p;
```

...gives...

```
(lldb) po c1.category (ItemCategory *) $2 = 0x06b98bd0 <ItemCategory: 0x6b98bd0> (entity: ItemCategory; id: 0x6b98ee0 <x-coredata:///ItemCategory/tB2F1219F-4FA5-48DA-871E-D9F9DC8E33E34> ; data: {
    category = nil;
    project = nil;
    subcategories =     (
        "0x6b82280 <x-coredata:///ItemCategory/tB2F1219F-4FA5-48DA-871E-D9F9DC8E33E33>"
    ); })
(lldb) po c1.project (Project *) $3 = 0x06b97a20 <Project: 0x6b97a20> (entity: Project; id: 0x6b97a70 <x-coredata:///Project/tB2F1219F-4FA5-48DA-871E-D9F9DC8E33E32> ; data: {
    categories =     (
        "0x6b82280 <x-coredata:///ItemCategory/tB2F1219F-4FA5-48DA-871E-D9F9DC8E33E33>"
    ); })
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't shed any light on **what** may be wrong but it doesn't seem inherently a restriction.